# how to select multiple radio buttons with different names with one label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, label

how to select multiple radio buttons with different names with one label?

here's a simple example of what i'm trying to achieve...

```
<input id="1A" type="radio" name="first" value="A">firstA<br>
<input id="1B" type="radio" name="first" value="B">firstB<br>
<input id="2A" type="radio" name="second">secondA<br>
<input id="2B" type="radio" name="second">secondB<br>
<input id="3A" type="radio" name="third">thirdA<br>
<input id="3B" type="radio" name="third">thirdB<br>
<label for="1A">
    <label for="2B">
        <label for="3A">
            <div>1A / 2B / 3A</div>
        </label>
    </label>
</label>
```

so when i click the "1A / 2B / 3A" i want it to select make a select 3 radio buttons (firstA, secondB, thirdA), any ideas?

Comment: got it working now! thanks for your help, guys! how y'all have a great day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the labels are always properly nested, the `click` event will propagate naturally.  You can just set the checked property manually then:

```
$("label").on('click', function () {
    $("#" + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/rT8x5/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="divId">1A / 2B / 3A</div>

$('#divId').click(function () {
    $('#1A').attr('checked', checked);
    $('#2B').attr('checked', checked);
    $('#3A').attr('checked', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give your div an id(unique)

```
 <div id="divID">1A / 2B / 3A</div>
```

call click function

```
 $('#divID').click(function(){
      $('#1A').prop('checked',true);
      $('#2B').prop('checked',true);
      $('#3A').prop('checked',true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override default behavior of label element to propagate click event to parent elements.

```
function bubbleLabelClick(e){
    $("#" + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
    return true;
}
$('label').click( bubbleLabelClick);
```

Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/phxjL/

The key point is `return true;` in function bubbleLabelClick.